# Subtract Time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Hi guys i need help to subtract the time. 7:31:52 AM - 4:30:32 the ouput is **3hrs 1 mins 20 sec**

```
Dim date1 = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 7, 30, 0, 0)
Dim date2 = DateTime.Parse("4:30:00 PM")

If read1("clog") Is (DBNull.Value) Then

Else
    date1 = read1("clog")
    Dim duration As Double = (date2 - date1).Minutes

    Label4.Text = duration
End If
```

Comment: If you want the time differenced then why are getting just the minutes?  Subtracting one `Date` from another produces a `TimeSpan` and that contains all the information you need.  Depending on your version of VB.NET, you may be able to use its `ToString` method to output the result as you want.  If not, use `String.Format` and use the appropriate components of that `TimeSpan` where required.  It has `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` properties.

Comment: sorry guys. the ouput is: 1mins 20 sec please help i am a beginner in vb.net. thank you in advance...

Comment: How is this related to MS-Access-2010? That tag should be removed if the code above is all VB.NET and not VBA

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim time1 As DateTime = #7/20/2016 7:31:52 AM#
        Dim time2 As DateTime = #7/20/2016 4:30:00 PM#
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = time2 - time1
        MsgBox(ts.Days & " day(s) " & ts.Hours & " hour(s) " & _
               ts.Minutes & " minute(s) " & ts.Seconds & " second(s)")


Dim date1 As DateTime


                    Dim date2 = DateTime.Parse("4:30:00 PM")

                    If read1("clog") Is (DBNull.Value) Then

                    Else

                        date1 = read1("clog")
                        Dim duration As TimeSpan = date2 - date1

                        Label4.Text = String.Format("{0} hour(s) {1} minute(S) {2} second(s)", duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds

                    End If
```

Comment: F0r3v3r-A-N00b time1 is PM time2 is AM i need to calculate the first in 7:31 PM to 4:30 PM. Time in 7:31 AM from database  date1 = read1("clog") to subtract the two time.

Comment: F0r3v3r-A-N00b Sir the Time1 is From the database Time in. I need to compute the total of Late. Thank you

Comment: so retrieve the data from your database and  perform the time computation.

Comment: F0r3v3r-A-N00b Thank you sir its working now but i need to subract for 1 hour for the lunch break... the output is 7hours, 58 minutes 8 Seconds

Comment: F0r3v3r-A-N00b  I found the answer... thank you very much